# Extracting tiles from a tileset programatically?

Tags: tiles, tilemap

How do I programatically extract tiles from a tileset such as this one:
http://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/grassland_tiles.png

I want to use these tiles in my game. I see that some tiles here are of different sizes (or maybe all tiles are a multiple of some fixed size). For example, if I want to use one of the tree tiles in my program, how can I figure out what offset into the tileset image I must use, and how big of a sub-image i must extract? I don't see any metadata associated with any of these tilesets that I can use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You generally need some text file or other metadata to describe the contents of a texture atlas like this.

I suspect you went here:
     http://opengameart.org/content/grassland-tileset
to get this URL?  (That would've been handy in your OP.)

If so, you must've missed this note:

> To use the tile set in Tiled v0.8, get the necessary files from the Flare git repo.

The git repo is: https://github.com/clintbellanger/flare/tree/master/tiled/grassland

Its got one `.txt` several `.tmx` files.  The `.tmx` files seem to describe the location of specific items in the atlases.